# Customize toolbar Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Is it possible to customize the Kendo Grid Tool bar. Currently I'm using this [Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing). 
In this demo I don't want use the Save Changes link in the tool bar, rather I want to use it like a submit button at the bottom of the grid which performs the validation. Is it possible? Need your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down the left menu in your linked demo, you'll find the [Toolbar Template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template) demo. That's a good place to start.

If you don't want a toolbar, then configure the grid without one. If you want the submit button below the grid, then it's as easy as putting a `<button/>` below the grid and wiring an event to trigger when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

use kendo grid toolbar template

```
 .ToolBar(toolBar =>
        {

            toolBar.Template(
                @<Text>

                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <div data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                            <button type="button" id="searchcategory" value="Name" class="btn btn-default btnstick">Name</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnstick"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                        </div>
                        <ul id="searchdropdown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a>Name</a></li>
                            <li><a>Description</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a>Any</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>                        </Text>);
        })
```